# Is the current 404 image final?

Tags: support

I'm considering posting a question for 404 image suggestions, but there seems to already be one. Is this specific to WebApps or just part of the construction theme?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sketchy theme is only for the beta.

Yes, we will definitely accept submissions / ideas for 404, error, and captcha themes when the site exits beta!

This ties into logo, domain name, and overall CSS design suggestions.

Answer (score 3):

It's for the Beta(Sketchy) theme only.